# Looking for backwards seach in string in BBx Business basic

Tags: business-basic, bbj

I look for a way to search in a string, starting from the last character.

I do have a solution with a for next loop and parse the string one by one. But there must be a smarter way to do this. I have tried to do this with

```
pos (" "=i$)
```

but this statement starts from the begin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop will do, but it's slow. There is a inbuild command you can use

```
I$="123 ABC DEF"
X = POS (" "=I$,-1)
```

This gives you the position of the last space in I$
result of this is 7

Another option is using MASK()  which is pretty much similar to the unix "grep"

Comment: greatm that's what i was looking for